# Java- populating 2d array element index randomly?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have a 5x5 2D array that is supposed to be populated with objects from another array that has the same dimensions. I need a loop that iterates until each spot is full with all of the objects from the other array. The row and column need to be random, and if the spot has already been filled then it needs to find an empty spot to fill it. For example, if the random spot is array[0][3] then it fills it then goes to a new spot like array[1][2]. I have Random rand = new Random() declared and declare `int row = rand.nextInt(4)` and `int col = rand.nextInt(4)` and `array[row][col]  = object`. How do i construct the loop that performs this action until all indices are populated?

Comment: A much simpler strategywould be to put all the elements of the original array in a List, to shuffle the list, and then to populate the new array from the shuffled list.

Comment: What data type are you using? This is important as when we populate the new array with a value from the existing array we need to check if the value at the random position is the default e.g default value for an int array is 0 If so we have a valid position to place a value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's code to radomize the order in which spots in the 2D array is filled.
If you need any further assistance on this feel free to ask.

```
ArrayList<Integer> inds= new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i=1; i<26;i++){
    inds.add(i);
}
while(inds.size()!=0){
    int x = rand.nextInt(inds.size());
    array[inds.get(x)/5][inds.get(x)%5] =  0; //replace 0 with what ever it is that you want to store
}
```